# How can I inspect 6" horizontal ducts to locate a rattle?

Tags: ducts, product-recommendation

Something is rattling somewhere in a 6" round metal ceiling HVAC duct network, not near any vents.  Maybe it's a loose damper.  The ducts are now behind finished wallboard and since the airflow to all vents is adequate it's not worth destructive inspection.

I was thinking that a cheap wired robot with camera – probably designed and sold as a toy – could crawl through the ducts to inspect them.  My search for such a product has only turned up 4-figure robots designed for commercial HVAC operations.

Are there any clever and inexpensive tools, robotic or otherwise, for inspecting deep into 6" round rigid ducts?

Comment: I have used a company that vacuums ducts in one case it was around a dozen hot wheels cars rolling around, might be less than other methods and you end up with dust free ductwork.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine needing anything more than a cheap borescope and a fish tape. The trick would be attaching the borescope in such a way that it doesn't collect gobs of lint as you work it down the duct.

I'd actually forego the camera to start and just knock a fish tape or light plumbing auger around a bit. Maybe you'll knock the thing into a more favorable position.

You could also work a powerful vacuum down there with hose extensions. Be sure to tape them together well to avoid a worse situation.

Comment: Problem is I don't actually know if it's a damper, and if it is I could just as easily knock it into a *less* favorable (more closed) position and then have no good way to open it back up.

Comment: There shouldn't be a damper in an inaccessible location.

Comment: @feetwet Apply length markings to the fish tape or auger before inserting. Pay attention to the feel and sound while inserting it -- at least if you do run into something, and if it does take a turn for the worse, you'll have a good idea where to open the drywall for a hands-on inspection and repair.